# c# Unity - how to call a struct object array in another class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, object, struct

In classA, I have an object array made from a struct. I want to call that object array in classB.

classA:

```
    public classA{ 
      public struct Item{
         public string name;
         public int price;
         public GameObject obj;
     }
     public Item[] itemList;
 }
```

class B:

```
 public classB{
 ////how do i call itemList and its properties(name, price, etc.) here???
 }
```

Comment: Take a reference of `classA` inside `classB` and use `classAReference.itemList [ 0 ].name`!!!!

Comment: How do you create a classAReference?

Comment: This [new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator) operator can help in the creation of `classAReference`. Else we need more information, how this is related to Unity in any way. This is a simple C# language question.

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```
public classA{ 
      public struct Item{
         public string name;
         public int price;
         public GameObject obj;
     }

     public Item[] itemList;
 }
```

To this:

```
public struct Item {
    public string name;
    public int price;
    public GameObject obj;
}


public classA {           
     public Item[] itemList;
 }
```

Comment: It's in two different files so this wouldnt work

Comment: Why would you do that? It is no issue at all that the type is nested under `classA` ...